# EC2 is no more available after a while

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I have a strange issue and I don't know where to look at.

I have a EC2 instance that is perfectly working where I have installed Airflow.
I can ssh to it and can access the AF instance.

But at a moment, I don't know why, the instance is no accessible, ssh, web or even from the aws console. I have a timeout. I need to reboot the instance to have it accessible.

What can I check to solve this ?

EDIT : maybe linked to this ?
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=961785&tstart=0

CloudWatch :

[image]

EDIT 2 :
I have detach and reattach an EBS instance. I may have been on a dysfunctional hardware here. First time in several years that happen if it's that.

Comment: What do the CloudWatch metrics look like?

Comment: @Maurice Is that enough ? Why do I have a CPU utilization around 30% at the same time I have the "Status check fail sum that goes up" ? I just have Airflow installed, no dag yet.

Comment: Is it an instance from the t-family?

Comment: nope it's the free tier (just the time I finish to set up everything).